# Trigger with time and date range

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I try to monitor a Windows process (if this process works or not) in a period of time.
Now I add only time range and it doesn't work. If it works I want to also add day of week range 1-5 --> 8:00-17:00, 6-7 --> 00:00 - 00:00.

My Zabbix version: 4.0

My test item:
proc.num[notepad.exe]

my test trigger:

0 - offline,
1 - online

```
{DELLRN7:proc.num[notepad.exe].avg(1m)}=0 and {DELLRN7:proc.num[notepad.exe].time()}>170000 or {DELLRN7:proc.num[notepad.exe].time()}<080000 and {DELLRN7:proc.num[notepad.exe].avg(1m)}=0
```

And it doesn't work.

Only when I set up to monitor 24/7 it is working:

```
{DELLRN7:proc.num[notepad.exe].avg(1m)}=0
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Richlv when notepad is offline, hour is grater then >170000 i have Value "OK" not "Problem" so condition don't work ;/

Comment: Problem solved, rules working with UTC time not the local time!